# Is Django design as good without css3 + html 5?

Tags: django, html, css

I've had a look at some really good website layout and design using Django, pinterest, (former)curse, disqus, and the django design template lpoks impressive.
Was just pondering thoughts as to were it is necessary to add css3 or html5 to enhance page design and interaction or would using Django features for eg. divs and headers, boxing text good enough or even better visually.
Lets for argument sake, say we are developing an extensive auction site like e-bay or networking site like facebook.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what CSS and HTML is. Django generates HTML - there's no web page without HTML.

Comment: yeah i do, that wasn't the question

Answer (score 4):

Django doesn't have any design. There is zero front-end included, so that if you made a template page and added divs/headers/whatnot in there it would have absolutely no custom formatting whatsoever beyond the specifications of vanilla HTML.

So if you want to design a site like Pinterest you'll definitely need your own CSS and HTML.

Answer (score -1):

So, django make a view with HTML and CSS (you will have some div..) but no div will be declared and you will have a white page withall things aligned to left..

It is not complicated, if you want a beautiful site (or just not hugly :)) you will need both html and css, but not last versions if you don't wand (but its better..)

Comment: cool so you would incorporate css and html styles in with your django? could you make a website as good as the impressive html5 and css3 just with the django framework?

Comment: When you read 'just with the django framework' it is **with html and css** too. They meens without Cake,PHP, Ruby on rails... If you want verify, look at the source code of one of your page...